Is my proof on elementary set theory correct?
I'm studying a pre-calculus book and the first chapter is about some basic set theory.
There's a proof writing problem and to be honest I'm pretty bad at writing proofs, so I'm looking for verification and possible improvements.
Suppose $A$ $\subset$ $B$ and $B$ $\subset$ $C$. Prove that $A$ $\subset$ $C$.
Proof: Let $x$ $\in$ $A$. Since $A$ $\subset$ $B$ then $x$ $\in$ $B$ and if $B$ $\subset$ $C$ then $x$ $\in$ $C$, thus $A$ $\subset$ $C$. $\square$

It's correct, but when/if I want to check how deeply understand somebody such proof I usually asked:  why holds "if $x \in A$ and $A \subset B$, then $x \in B$"?

I think you have to add "for any x"

@trula, usually, in such situations, when we start sentence with "let x be .." we mean "any", because we did not mention any restriction. Generally many depends on context.

@zkutch Well, $A \subseteq B \Longleftrightarrow (\forall y \in A) y \in B$.

@K. Jiang, I agree as $(\forall x R)S$ we understand as $(\forall x )(R \rightarrow S)$.

I would use a little more language. Communication is very important in proofs. The goal is not to make them as terse as possible. Let $x\in A$. Assuming $A\subset B$, by definition of subset, $x\in A$ implies $x\in B$. Since $B$ is a subset of $C$ and we know $x\in B$, again by the definition of subset, $x\in B$ implies $x\in C$. We have shown then that if $x\in A$ then $x\in C$. Therefore, by definition $A\subset C$.

@DavidP I'm not a native speaker, so this sounds like a genuine advice. Thanks!

As I wrote in comment, proof is correct. To look slightly insight one can add, that when you create sentence "if $x \in A$ and $A \subset B$, then $x \in B$" in addition to the fact that you use the subset definition you implicitly use $\Big ( p \land (p \Rightarrow q)\Big) \Rightarrow q$ and that this is tautology also needs proof.

This seems like an elementary discrete mathematics course. Logic is usually taught afterwards

Of course it all depends on the place where it is taught. I think that the elements of logic should precede the definitions and exercises on sets, since they are used in formal definitions.
